# How to code split-step Fourier method in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, vector-fields

I need to solve the following split-step equation in Matlab:

$$u(x+\Delta x, z)=\text{exp}\bigg(ik(n^2-1)\frac{\Delta x}{2}\bigg)F^{-1}\bigg(\text{exp}\bigg[-ip^2\frac{\Delta x}{2k}\bigg]F\{u(x,z\}\bigg)$$

I have an initial field $u(0,z)$, which is a vector, and I want the Matlab to find $u(x+\Delta x, z)$ for some range $x$. Effectively i want something like this:

[image]

In my head when I code something like this:

```
xmax=2600; 
delx=50;  % step size in x
x = delx:delx:xmax;

 for i = delx:delx:xmax;   
   c1=fftshift(fft(u0z));
   c2=exp(-1j*(p^2.*x/(2*k))).*c1;
   c3=ifft(ifftshift(c2));
   u0z=exp(1j*k.*(n.^2-1).*x./2).*c3;
 end
```

The program should use my initial vector $u0z$, feed it and find the value of $u(x+\Delta x, z)$. Then it should feed the new value and use it to find $u(x+2\Delta x, z)$ and so on, but it doesn't. It just gives me a $1 x n$ row vector at the end.

I am sure there is something wrong with how I am implementing code, and perhaps even how I use the fft commands, but I don't really know Matlab. Would anyone be willing to help? Thanks.

P.S. I could paste my whole code if required, but it is long and messy.

EDIT:

```
for i=1:1:length(x)
   c1=fftshift(fft(u0z));
   c2=exp(-1j*(p^2*x(i)/(2*lamda))).*c1;
   c3=ifft(ifftshift(c2));
   u0z=exp(1j*lamda*(n(i)^2-1)*x(i)/2).*c3;
end
```

Comment: You want to wind up with a matrix at the end? Then you need to save the rows you are generating along the way accordingly.

Comment: yes, looking back at the image I added i want a vertical field made up of a discrete number of points spaced evenly between $0$ and $z_max$. And i want this field found for however many step sizes in $x$  I get. Any idea of how to make this process automatic?

Comment: Then you want something like u(:,i)=... where i=1,2...

Comment: Ive edited it, i think I am getting closer to something, but I have no idea where to add the u(:,i).When I add it on the last line iI get the following error:

" Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is length(x)-by-1 and the size of the right side is length(x)-by-2."

Comment: This is a question about Matlab, not mathematics. Voting to close as off-topic.